# How to handle space in UNC path in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

The Windows server my team uses recently got upgraded. A batch file, which used to work fine, is now not working due to spacing in a directory path.  I believe the `robocopy` command is failing.

How can I get the command to work properly and recognize the space in the directory path correctly?

Batch file code:

```
@ECHO OFF
:start

rem GOTO end

if exist %1*_desc.xml (
  del %1*_desc.xml
  goto final
)
:final
rem Rename files with -en-us
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "Pattern=-en-us"
set "Replace="
for %%# in (%1*.*) do (
    set "File=%%~nx#"
    ren "%%#" "!_File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
:end

copy %1*.* %2*.*

::robocopy "%1" "%2" *.*
```

Command being executed:

```
D:\scripts\Maintenance\COGCleanup.bat  "\\nycb\corp$\group\IT\IT-NY\Application Development\CognosTest\"
```

Output error message:

```
\\nycb\corp$\group\IT\IT-NY\Application Development\CognosTest\*.* 

Access is denied.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

**NOTE:** In the above error message, the first part of the directory (before access is denied) is underlined and in blue. I can't replicate it here. The space after `Application` is what's causing the issue I believe.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd/?` and read the output help carefully and completely. Then run `call /?` and read again the entire output help. I strongly recommend to replace `if exist %1*_desc.xml` by `if exist "%~1*_desc.xml"` and replace `for %%# in (%1*.*) do` by `for %%# in ("%~1*") do`. There is the command __START__ as it can be seen on running `help` or `start /?`. It is possible to name a label `start` by using in a batch file `:start`, but it is advisable to avoid a command name as label name. I suggest to use `:begin`.

Comment: thank you for all the comments!  The process is functioning now.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the command you used:

```
D:\scripts\Maintenance\COGCleanup.bat  "\\nycb\corp$\group\IT\IT-NY\Application Development\CognosTest\"
```

`%1` is `"\\nycb\corp$\group\IT\IT-NY\Application Development\CognosTest\"` (quotes included).

`%1*.*` is `"\\nycb\corp$\group\IT\IT-NY\Application Development\CognosTest\"*.*`

`"%1"` is `""\\nycb\corp$\group\IT\IT-NY\Application Development\CognosTest\""` and will be parsed as 2 parameters `\\nycb\corp$\group\IT\IT-NY\Application` and `Development\CognosTest\`.

You can fix is by using `"%~1"` (with quotes).

`%~1` is `%1` without quotes, if there are quotes. No matter if `%1` is `"foo"` or `foo`, `%~1` is always `foo`, and `"%~1"` is always `"foo"`

Comment: Thank you for all the comments!  I appreciate the assist.  The process is functioning again.